# Slow OLAP cube (SQL views index)

Tags: sql, performance, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I made a OLAP cube in JaserSoft-OLAP Workbench but i have big Problem with the Performance.

Im using 5 views that contains only the data i need for my cube. My facttable (view) is pretty big an has 3 Million rows and a select * from that view takes 40 sec to run.

The other 4 views are pretty small and works as dimensions in my Cube.

I tried to set index on my views but it's impossible to set index on a view that contians Union Statements.

Now i have no idea how i can achieve a better Performance... Somebody have an idea?

If you want to see some code from my views it's no Problem.

Comment: you can create indexes on your tables. How big are the underlying tables? Also, are you talking about cube browsing performance or cube processing performance?